# How can I build a seq2seq model , which is topic aware

Tags: keras, lstm, sequence-to-sequence

I have developed a chatbot, which is basically a seq2seq LSTM network. Which can generate text based on input text. But the problem I am having right now is it is not topic aware.
As an example :

Input : Wanna go to the stadium ? Topic: Football

Answer: No , I don't like football.

What I am planning to do , is to tokenize each possible topic

As an example `{1: "Football",2: "Food" ..........}`

But don't know how to embed this tokenized topic in training .

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach (not embedded but filtering your model) with Topic modeling, that could be used to filter the results of your model by topic:

1. Separate each doc in several sentences
2. Obtain the best topics ( occur > 3, chars > 3 ) from sentences if you do not have an idea of topics to declare (LatentDirichlet Allocation)
3. Discard some topics out of interest

Finally assign a dominant topic to every sentence and filter results by topic.

I have found a reference from steps 1-3:
https://medium.com/@actsusanli/when-topic-modeling-is-part-of-the-text-pre-processing-294b58d35514